# Run Google Sheet Add-On as Admin

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I have three spreadsheets (Files) with three different users. Tech SSheet, Admin SSheet and Manager SSheet. Tech SSheet data should be sent to Manager SSheet when Tech user click on the Add-On.

Admin user is Owner of all three files. Tech user doesn't have access to Manager SSheet. All the code is placed in Admin Sheet and Add on is created. So here I have to call code in Admin Sheet from Tech Sheet/user.

I created Add-On but it is taking Tech Sheet as reference. Since Tech Sheet do not have permission to Manager Sheet, copy data is failing.

Is there any possibility to run Add-on as Admin without providing permission to Tech user?

Comment: I guess you can use installable triggers

Comment: When you speak of Tech Sheet, Admin Sheet and Manager Sheet are you talking about Spreadsheets or tabs(i.e. called Sheets in the Google Apps Script documentation)

Comment: Permissions are granted to users, not to "sheets".

Comment: What means "Tech Sheet doesn't have access to Manager Sheet"?

Comment: Thank you TheMaster. Can you please share any sample code available for Installable Trigger?

Comment: Yes Ruben, Tech Users do not have access manager spreadsheet. But data should be copied using Add-on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a possibility to do it - with a **service account**.

### Workflow

- [Create Google Service account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7378726?hl=en), enable domain-wide delegation and provide it with the necessary scopes
- Share your Manager SSheet with the service account
- Write an Apps Script function to [obtain an Access Token for the service account](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2)
- Use this token for the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets) to copy data into the Manager SSheet

This allows the user to pass data from his spreadsheet to your spreadsheet to which the user does not have access, but the service account has.

> Below is a script for an Add-on that will format data from user´s spreadsheet
> into to CSV and paste them into Manager SSheet with
> [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)

```
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen(e) {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Copy sheet')
      .addItem('Copy now', 'run')
      .addToUi();
}

function run() { 
  var service = getService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    copySheet(service);  
  } else {
    Logger.log(service.getLastError());
  }
}

function getService() {
  var PRIVATE_KEY ="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----  XXX_YOUR_KEY_XXX  -----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
  var CLIENT_EMAIL = 'XXXX@XXXX-XXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com'; 
  return OAuth2.createService('myServiceAccount')
      .setTokenUrl('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token')
      .setPrivateKey(PRIVATE_KEY)
      .setIssuer(CLIENT_EMAIL)
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
      .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets');
}

function copySheet(service){  
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var valueRange=sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var data='';
  for(var i=0;i<valueRange.length;i++){
   for(var j=0;j<valueRange[0].length;j++){
    data+=(valueRange[i][j]+",");
    }
   data+=("\n")
  }  
  var dId='ID_OF_Manager SSheet';      
  if(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getKeys().length==0){
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('i', '2');
     }   
  var i=parseInt(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('i'));
  var url='https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/'+dId+':batchUpdate';
  var body = {requests: [
            {
                "addSheet": {
                  "properties": {
                  "sheetId": i
                  } 
               }
             },{
                "pasteData": {
                  "data": data,
                  "type": "PASTE_NORMAL",
                  "delimiter": ",",
                  "coordinate": {
                  "sheetId": i,
                  "rowIndex": 0,
                  "columnIndex": 0
                   }
                  }
                }
              ]
             };
      
  var options = {
   "method":"post",
   "muteHttpExceptions": true,
   "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + service.getAccessToken()
     },
   "contentType": "application/json", 
   "payload": JSON.stringify(body)
   }      
  var r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);      
  if(r.getResponseCode()==200){
        PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('i', i+1);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Hi ziganotschka, Thanks for your solution. I am new to APIs. Can you please share more resources? I currently developed a plugin and it is working fine but it required to have permission to manager sheet. Now I want to develop with API. Please help me with more details. Thank You.

Comment: Have a look at the following two links, the first one is a sample of how to set-up a service account with Apps Script, the second one is the quickstart for the usage of Sheets API: https://ctrlq.org/code/20375-service-accounts-google-apps-script https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/apps-script

Comment: Hi ziganotschka, Can you please help me answer this questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65477903/run-google-sheets-add-on-as-different-user?noredirect=1#comment115764629_65477903

Comment: I am getting below error,
ReferenceError: OAuth2 is not defined
at getService (SubmitData:26)
at RunService (SubmitData:13)

Answer (score 0):

On G Suite document editors, including Google Sheets, if the documents are on "My Unit" and not on a "Shared Unit" (formerly "Team Drive") the permissions roles are

- Owner
- Editor
- Commenter
- Viewer

In other words, there is no "admin", by the other hand, permissions are granted to users not to "sheets".

References

- [Share files from Google Drive](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494822?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: I have one user called Admin. He is owner of all three spreadsheets. I want to give permission only to code. Tech User should not be able to edit Manager spreadsheet but code should copy data.

Comment: @SaiKrishna Please edit your question to clarify that and if "Admin Sheet", "Tech Sheet" and "Manager Sheet" are spreadsheets (each one is a file) or if they are sheets (tabs) of on spreadsheet.