# Is there a way to assign a trigger ownership from Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

I have a problem with triggers and permissions in Drive, about Forms:

- There is a **shared folder** with Forms.
- All these Forms are of **my property** (I'm the owner)
- **Everyday**, some other user with editor permissions, copy one of them
  to another shared folder.
- That 'some other user' is the **new owner** of that copy.
- That copy has a Script (like the original Form) that when you open,
  it perform 2 actions:
- ```
  Change the owner of the Form to me
  ```
- ```
  Set up a trigger to delete the Form
  ```

The problem is, at the moment of create the trigger, that the Script doesn't notice that the owner has changed **during the execution**. So, I own the file at the end, but the script is not allowed to delete the file when the time comes, because is not me the "author" or owner of that trigger.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Maybe the solution is the most simple of the ways: Leave unchanged the owner of the Form and, in that way, at the moment of firing up the trigger, both, the trigger's owner and the Form's owner, are the same user

Comment: A trigger is owned by the user that owns the project that created it.

Comment: That's what I thought. But I encountered that a trigger is owned by the user who created. I just made a test today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### An installable trigger always runs on behalf of the person who created it - that is the person who authorized the trigger by signing in with his account

If your set-up is such, that a user needs to delete a form owned by you, he needs to do it on your behalf.

Possible configurations:

**1. In corporate into the code a call to a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)**

- If you deploy the WebApp as `Execute the app as: Me` and `Who has access to the app:Anyone within [your domain]` - then everybody who calls the WebApp by its deployment URL can execute it on your behalf (you can also pass parameters to the WebApp by addining them as a query string to the URL)

**2. Use a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) with [impersonation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)**

- This will ensure that a script always runs on the behalf of the impersonated user (can be you!), no matter who runs the code
- See [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57914331/11599789)

Comment: Thanks ziganotschka! Great ideas. I forgot to describe one situation where troubles can be found...if the form is created by someone else than me, then the idea of web app just can't do it, and I'll never know who is gonna be the owner next time.
I say that because, if someone create the form, and eventually I update it, so a trigger under my authority is created to delete de form. But, the form is not my own. So...you can see the problem there. It's all messed up

Comment: In this case you can still use a service account - this also allows to transfer ownership of the form to you.