# Request WebApp from GAS (inside a GSheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, oauth, urlfetch

I spent a lot of time past days reading posts about my topic but I didn't find the solution.

1. A created a simple (standalone) WebApp that modify a Sheets (appendRow for this example). This WebApp is executes AS ME and EveryOne  has access :

```js
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log("Call WebApi ok");
  //var idSheet = e.parameter.idu;
  var idSheet = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  //Logger.log(idSheet);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idSheet);
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('tab1');
  sh.appendRow(["Test"]);
}
```

2. Inside the Google Sheets, I created the (caller) script.

```js
function go() {
  var url = "https://script.google.com/a/AAAAA/macros/s/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/exec";
  var params = {
    method: "get",
    headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params);
}
```

The caller script have the follwong scopes in manifest :

```js
"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
```

-> If I execute the caller script with a different account that the WebApp owner, it doesn't work.
I get a 403 error.

-> However, if I open the URL of the Publish WebApp in Chrome, it works !

Do you have an idea why it doesn't work from the caller script from the Sheets ?

Thnaks !
Luis

Comment: According to the Stackoverflow guidelines, you should provide additional information by either [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64496793/request-webapp-from-gas-inside-a-gsheets) your question or commenting on it / on the provided answers. I will thus vote to delete the answers you provided, since they are not satisfactory solutions of your problem. I will provide additional information to your problem by updating my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your WebApp is deployed publicly, you **do not need to provide authorization headers** to fetch the WebApp , neither do you need to provide oauth scopes.

However, if the WebApp is called from a script - in incognito mode, it is not enough to deploy it as "Anyone can access".

### You need to publish it as "Anyone, even anonymous".

UPDATE

If publishing your WebApp with access to "Anyone, even anonymous" is not an acceptable solution for you, and callig the WebApp from the browser nither,  you need to implement a different approach.

For implementing requests that shall only be authorized for your domain, the most appropiate solution would be using a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) with [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegate-domain-wide-authority).

This means:

- DO NOT create a WebApp
- Implement the code currently contained in the WebApp inot the script called by the user
- If you create a service account and allow domain-wide delegation, this means that any user of your domain will be able to perform a request (for which you authorized the scopes) on your behalf - without the need of a WebApp.
- To implement a service account in Google Apps Script, you need to use the [apps-script-oauth2 library](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2)
- See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57661513/run-google-sheet-add-on-as-admin/57914331#57914331) for an implementaiton sample

Comment: Doesn't work without getOAuthTocken. I'm not in incognito mode.

Comment: It works for me when deploying as "anyone, even anonymous" - this is important! Also, make sure you have correct deployment URL. Use the syntax https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXXXXX/exec

Comment: Hi, I finaly find the solution (in reality, a frien of mine at work ;) I just share the script WebApp with everybody in Corporate (READ). And now it works !

Comment: Hi, in my company we cannont publish "Anyone, even anonymous", but only "Me" or "Corporate". I Choose "Corporate". I finally solved the issue by sharing the WebApp script with the follong rôle : Anyone in Corporate with the link can read.

Comment: I understand. This is why I provided you a waorkaround in my updated answer - if you are interested.

Comment: Hi ziganotschka ! Thanks for your workaround. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code, and the caller script works fine when executing it as WebApp owner or with any other account. The only scenario it fails, is when executed in incognito mode (some Google apps script functions behave weird in incognito).

try not to execute it in incognito or since you are not using **getOAuthToken** change your **go()** function as shown below

```
function go() {
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://script.google.com/a/AAAAA/macros/s/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/exec");
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work without getOAuthTocken. I'm not in incognito mode.