# Run Google Sheets Add-On as different user

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two sheets as "Enquiry" and "Master" with owner as "Admin". In enquiry sheet, I protected few columns and shared across users. Users enter data in enquiry sheet and click on plugin (Add-on). The plugin will copy data to master sheet and enters some data in locked cells.

Plugin (Add-on) is throwing error because it is not able to edit locked cells. So I want the plugin (Add-on) to run with Admin account rather than user account or any other way to achieve this solution.

Note: Admin and Users are of different domains.

Thank You very much in advance.

Comment: By `plugin` do you mean Add-on?

Comment: Yes, I have created Add-on as "Submit Data" . Below is code used to copy data to master sheet.
Master_Sheet.getRange(Master_Sheet_lr + 2, 2, user_data_lr, user_data_lc).setValues(user_data);

Comment: Perhaps, you can create a web app which runs as the admin, which in its doGet() method, makes the edits to the cells. Would this be an acceptable workaround for you?

Comment: Yes Rafa Guillermo. Thank You